# Gitpod Self-Host failed

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-20.04, gitpod

[Comand `$ kubectl kots install gitpod` failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkvTZ.png)

[Error screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWhDK.jpg)

I installed K8S, kubectl and another necessary utilities for Gitpod.
But the last step, `$ kubectl kots install gitpod` filed with the error (attached image)

Please help me out if anybody has experiences of installing Gitpod self-hosted.
I attempted it on my AWS EC2 (Ubuntu 20.04).

Thanks

Comment: very wild guess/obviously you did not even try troubleshooting it yourself: your cluster does not have dynamic PVC provisioning support, minio won't start. Regardless: look at your cluster, try to figure out what's going on. If you can't track down those issues: you shouldn't be granted access to k8s api, especially verbs such as create/delete. That would be dangerous

Comment: Thanks for your message.
I am not sure what you are talking about.
Could you please explain more detail?

Comment: Sorry for being ignorance of knowledge.
I am a newbie for K8S. How to check PVC, sir?

Comment: `kubectl get pvc`. Try to familiarize yourself with kubernetes CLI, Try to investigate the problem yourself / don't expect someone to guess: there are no two clusters alike, we don't know anything about your setup, ... you should be able to answer questions such as "how to check PVC" by yourself. Kubernetes docs are pretty well made and maintained.